# How can I postMessage to self in a Chrome Extension background page?

Tags: google-chrome-extension

I spent a while separating functionalities from one other:

1. queue functionality (accepts events to modify the queue, step, etc)
2. background functionality (accepts events to run background privileged tasks)
3. frontend functionality (accepts events to run frontend privileged tasks)

Each of these systems use message passing to drive task automation:

```
{ type: 'WORKFLOW_ACTION', name: 'ADD_TASK_TO_QUEUE', details }
{ type: 'WORKFLOW_ACTION', name: 'BEGIN_NEXT_TASK', details }
{ type: 'BACKGROUND_ACTION', name: 'OPEN_NEW_TAB', details }
{ type: 'BACKGROUND_ACTION', name: 'REMOVE_TAB', details }
{ type: 'CONTENT_SCRIPT_ACTION', name: 'SCROLL_PAGE', details }
```

However, I have noticed that using `port.postMessage()` from a background context does not arrive in the `port.onMessage.addListener(onMessage)` in another background context.  It seems that background scripts must directly invoke one another, and I have the potential for circular dependencies, since the queue can invoke background functionality, and the background functionality can modify the queue. I know `window.postMessage` does not exist in a background context either, so my question is this:

How can I emit a message from a background context to it's own context?

Comment: No, it won't work. This is the intended behavior. You can use your own event system.

Comment: An example of another approach could be `document.dispatchEvent`, since all background scripts are added to the same generated background page.